# Error trying to add fragment for facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#step1

I want to make a facebook login in my app. I followed this official tutorial from facebook. I replaced "extends Activity" with "extends FragmentActivity" and created the class MainFragment.java like it is said in the tutorial. When it comes to replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
```

with

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
    .commit();
} else {
    // Or set the fragment from restored state info
    mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
}
}
```

I am getting errors at the line .add und in the else statement:

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MainFragment)

and

Cannot cast from Fragment to MainFragment

Furthermore I'm not sure if it's correct to use android.R.id.content. Am I not supposed to replace content with my layout.xml ?

Thanks !

EDIT: My imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;


 import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Request;
```

Comment: I could solve these two errors. The problem was the wrong import in my MainFragment class.

Comment: Hi! Could you please tell me which import(s) from the list is(are) incorrect? It'd be really helpful if you could also post and answer to your question below. (I promise to upvote! ;-) )

Comment: What do you mean with "incorrect" ?

Comment: Can you post a more context on the `MainFragment` class you've created? Does this `MainFragment` class `extend Fragment`?

Answer (score 5):

In the `MainFragment` Class, delete

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

and add

```
android.support.v4.app.*;
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add  `import android.support.v4.app.*;` in the `MainFragment` class: